# Change current branch and commit to a new branch in Git

Tags: git

I have already created a new branch (C) in Git manually via bitbucket. Now I want to push changes from branch A to branch C.

I am on dir A now and commit & pushed a change to this branch.

```
directoryA > git status
On branch A
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/A'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Now I went to dir B. When I do `git status` it is connected to branch B but I want this dir to be connected to branch C

```
directoryB > git status
On branch B
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/B'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   .gitignore
        modified:   config/development.json

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

So should I do `git fetch && git checkout C` staying in directoryB and then commit & push.

Please suggest. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Your use of "dir" and "branch" seems very confused to me.  I don't understand what you are trying to do here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen dir A is dev platform and dir B is staging platform.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Different worktrees with different branches checked out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try what you have suggested it will work. To be clear providing the details again

```
 git fetch && git checkout C 
 git commit -am "what ever message you want to put"
```

The Above command will commit `.gitignore,config/development.json` and you can just push to the remote.

Comment: Yes that git fetch and checkout worked. Many thanks. It worked.